# Robot framework setup is not working in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework

I'm new to python and I'm trying to learn the python robot framework, I have updated all the required plugin's, packages but when I'm executing the testcase it is throwing error `module Object not found`. I have tried all the suggestions in the online but still facing the same error. can some one please help me in this.

***Packages Installed***
1.robotframework
2.robotframework-seleniumlibrary
3.selenium

***Plugin in Pycharm***
1.intellibot (Latest version)
2.robot framework Support

***robot file***

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
LoginTest
    create webdriver    chrome    executable_path="C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\chromedriver_win32_new\chromedriver.exe"
    go to    https://google.com

*** Keywords ***
```

***Console***

```
C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\RobotF2>robot Test2.robot
==============================================================================
Test2
==============================================================================
LoginTest                                                             | FAIL |
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test2                                                                 | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\RobotF2\output.xml
Log:     C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\RobotF2\log.html
Report:  C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\RobotF2\report.html
```

And one more thing is, I have python installed in appdata/roaming/python/python 39 path and in Program Files folder.. In Pycharm, I have interpreter have choosen the python of Program Files..but env variable target to roaming/python folder and all the ibstalled packages are loaded inside of roaming/Python
/python39/Lib/site-package folder, so does I need to set the interpreter path in pycharm to roaming python folder??

Comment: Which keyword fails? What does the log.html say? Use the `Open Browser` keyword instead of the `Create Webdriver`.

Comment: So do you mean that there is no issue with python interpreter that i have selected?.. And the syntax of open browser is same like create Webdriver keyword??.. I mean setting path of chrome executable file

Comment: I do not know about the interpreter, I am just making suggestions you could try.  `Open Browser` is a convenient keyword that abstracts the web driver creation etc. it is documented in detail about how to use it. As for the chrome driver include its path in the PATH env variable.

Comment: @bencekaulics, sure.. I will try with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

***Try the following:***

1. When using chrome, download the latest chrome driver and also update the chrome browser to the latest version. The old chrome browser will not be triggered if you are using the latest version of the chrome driver.
2. Put your python folder and chrome driver in the path of environment variables. Or you can just copy the chrome driver file inside the python folder and it will automatically be in path.
3. Use the following code and run

   ```
   *** Settings ***
       Library    SeleniumLibrary     

   *** Test Cases ***

        LoginTest
           Open Browser    https://google.com    chrome
   ```

The chrome browser should open successfully running google.com